# My navigation.addListener().. not working with a console inside

Tags: react-native, navigation, use-effect

```
useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    console.log('Testeeee');
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

This code return this error:

Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up. You returned: [object Object];

Comment: returned obj isnt an error. anyway, do you know how useEffect works ?